# You can do ..., but you can't do

Tags: phrase-request, redundancy

Is there a smarter way to say

> You can do <...>, but you can't do <...>.

? Sounds very dumb to me. I think it's better to avoid such self-repeating.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

> You can do <...>, but not <...>.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept it in 10 minutes.

Comment: Still waiting...